# Elastic Search Reindexing failing silently

Tags: elasticsearch, elastic-stack

I am trying semantic search in elastic search following this [tutorial](https://www.elastic.co/blog/how-to-deploy-nlp-text-embeddings-and-vector-search).

When I am copying an index documents to another index [reindexing] following this command

```
POST _reindex?wait_for_completion=false
{
  "source": {
    "index": "collection"
  },
  "dest": {
    "index": "collection-with-embeddings",
    "pipeline": "text-embeddings"
  }
}
```

Some of the documents are missing in the new index. But I do not know the reason. I am trying to find out the reason.

For context,

```
PUT _ingest/pipeline/text-embeddings
{
  "description": "Text embedding pipeline",
  "processors": [
    {
      "inference": {
        "model_id": "sentence-transformers__msmarco-minilm-l-12-v3",
        "target_field": "text_embedding",
        "field_map": {
          "text": "text_field"
        }
      }
    }
  ],
  "on_failure": [
    {
      "set": {
        "description": "Index document to 'failed-<index>'",
        "field": "_index",
        "value": "failed-{{{_index}}}"
      }
    },
    {
      "set": {
        "description": "Set error message",
        "field": "ingest.failure",
        "value": "{{_ingest.on_failure_message}}"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

This is tasks details

```
{
    "completed": true,
    "task": {
        "node": "YgR8udaSSMqClwCGWOBGBw",
        "id": 5946104,
        "type": "transport",
        "action": "indices:data/write/reindex",
        "status": {
            "total": 2414,
            "updated": 1346,
            "created": 1068,
            "deleted": 0,
            "batches": 3,
            "version_conflicts": 0,
            "noops": 0,
            "retries": {
                "bulk": 0,
                "search": 0
            },
            "throttled_millis": 0,
            "requests_per_second": -1.0,
            "throttled_until_millis": 0
        },
        "description": "reindex from [source_index] to [destination_index]",
        "start_time_in_millis": 1680795982705,
        "running_time_in_nanos": 22702121635,
        "cancellable": true,
        "cancelled": false,
        "headers": {}
    },
    "response": {
        "took": 22699,
        "timed_out": false,
        "total": 2414,
        "updated": 1346,
        "created": 1068,
        "deleted": 0,
        "batches": 3,
        "version_conflicts": 0,
        "noops": 0,
        "retries": {
            "bulk": 0,
            "search": 0
        },
        "throttled": "0s",
        "throttled_millis": 0,
        "requests_per_second": -1.0,
        "throttled_until": "0s",
        "throttled_until_millis": 0,
        "failures": []
    }
}
```

My data is different, But the Configuration is similar. Around 75% data were not copied.

I am using `sentence-transformers__msmarco-minilm-l-12-v3` from elastic search.

Any Help?

Comment: When running with `wait_for_completion=false` you get a task id, you can then see how it goes and why it failed by checking the task details with `GET _tasks/<taskid>`. Could be circuit breakers, not enough memory to run the inference model, etc. Can you update your question with those details?

Comment: apology, I added the task details now

Comment: Ok, everything went fine, but as you can see out of 2414 documents, 1068 new ones were created and 1346 were updated, so maybe that's where you count difference comes from ?

Comment: Yes, I count them from `match_query`. But I do not understand the reason; It was the description field which I am trying to do embedding.

i tried to do that multiple times. Interestingly the count in the destination index is different every time.

Comment: Maybe show your query and response from source and destination index

Comment: This is the query. 
`{
    "query": {
        "match_all": {}
    }
}
`
to search all documents 

destination index return  total 1368 documents and source index return 2414 documents as you can see from task details already

Comment: Do you have several source indexes where multiple documents might have the same `_id`?

Comment: I have just one source index. And I am assigning the `_id` field incrementally from code.  It is unique, I can say.

Comment: What happens if you delete the destination index and start anew?

Comment: Yes, I tried it. But the same result. But If I do not delete it and reindex it repeatedly, the document count increases by around 100 in the destination every time. So it may be a memory issue, as you said earlier.
Is there any batch reindexing I can do?
Howw can I overcome it?

Comment: If there's a memory issue, the task should contain the details 

Comment: Oh, okay; if I reindex to the existing destination every time, num of documents increases.
What could be the possible reason?

Comment: Do you have any documents landing in `failed-collection-with-embeddings` ? If yes, what do you see in the `ingest.failure` field?

Comment: Yes, the rest of the one, which is not in the dest index, goes there.

Comment: Ok so that means there are ingest failures... which are the missing documents from the destination index, right?

Comment: Yes, right. But ingestion failure decreases if I try repeatedly as I said earlier

Comment: Yes, but my question is what do you see in the `ingest.failure` field?

Comment: Oh, good catch; I did not know about it.
this is what I see
`"ingest": {
                        "failure": "timeout [10s] waiting for inference result"
                    }`

Comment: There we go, you have your reason! Not enough processing power. What you do do is to use smaller batches (specifying a smaller `size` in source) or [throttling](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-reindex.html#docs-reindex-throttle)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably don't have enough processing power for the inference processor, and as a result, some documents land in the `failed-collection-with-embeddings` index with the reason mentioned in the `ingest.failure` field.

What you can do is to use smaller batches (specifying a smaller `size` in source) or use [request throttling](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-reindex.html#docs-reindex-throttle).

Comment: Thanks a lot, Val. I  signed off today already. I will try it, and if it works, I will accept your answer.

Comment: Hey, @Val. Sorry for the late reply. I tried it today with `requests_per_second`. And It is now working. Thanks a lot. I accept the answer.

Comment: Hi @val,  can you suggest to me how much memory/gpu/cpu should I use to run ml models in elastic search?